# How does ADO.NET identify unique connection strings

Tags: ado.net, .net-4.5, sql-server-2017

I am working on a legacy application where connection details are stored in an external file in an encrypted format. The application creates connection string at run time based on certain keywords that are passed to the function "GetConnectionString" that returns the connection string.

In one of the modules, I want to create a connection with a different application pool size. At the same time, I want to different the connection originating from this module with a different application name.

However, in SQL Server profiler the application name of the connection made by this module is the same as the rest of the application.

Does ADO.NET exclude connection pool size and application name while identifying a unique connection?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nothing is technically excluded. If Min Pool Size or Max Pool Size are not explicitly set in the connection string, the defaults are used:

- Max Pool Size: Maximum number of connections allowed in the pool. The
  default is 100.
- Min Pool Size: Minimum number of connections maintained in the
  pool. The default is 0.

To be clear, pools are created based on unique connection strings.

Per the [Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/sql-server-connection-pooling):

**Pool Creation and Assignment**

> When a connection is first opened, a connection pool is created based
>   on an exact matching algorithm that associates the pool with the
>   connection string in the connection. Each connection pool is
>   associated with a distinct connection string. When a new connection is
>   opened, if the connection string is not an exact match to an existing
>   pool, a new pool is created. Connections are pooled per process, per
>   application domain, per connection string and when integrated security
>   is used, per Windows identity. **Connection strings must also be an
>   exact match; keywords supplied in a different order for the same
>   connection will be pooled separately**.

**Adding Connections**

> A connection pool is created for each unique connection string

Comment: Thank you William for your response. I have read the documentation but the definition of unique connection string is not clear. e.g. it doesn't say if the connection strings "server=mysqlserver.com;user=admin;pwd=admin;db=mydb" and "server=mysqlserver.com;user=admin;pwd=admin;db=mydb;application name=myapp;maxcachesize=80" are the same but that is the behavior I observed in the profiler

Comment: The docs are clear. Connection strings MUST BE exact (including case) to be be taken from the same connection pool. The examples in your comment are not the same and therefore will not be associated with the same connection pool. My answer stands.

Comment: The behavior that I observed is different. In my scenario both application name and max pool size were different. However, the application name captured by sql server profiler was the same.

Comment: Your original question asks "Does ADO.NET exclude connection pool size and application name while identifying a unique connection?" and I answered the question. If the profiler is showing you connections with different application names and max pool sizes - that means the connection strings are associated with different connection pools.

Comment: On the contrary despite having different connection pool size and application name, ado.net uses the same connection pool. This is the only plausible explanation for profiler capturing the same application name in both the cases (rest of the application vs custom module). Had there been different application pools application names would have been different.

Comment: Within SQL Profiler - ApplicationName refers to the name of the client application that created the connection (ApplicationName will be the value specified in the connection string, or if none is specified), NOT the pool it was associated with it.

Comment: That is correct. So in my test I set a different application name for both the execution paths. Since connections are used from connection pools and if I assume that application name is one of the parameters to identify unique connections, I should have seen different application names in profiler.

Comment: I can't explain what you are experiencing with SQL Profiler, but whatever it is has nothing to do with connection pools. Connections are assigned to pools based on the value of the connection string itself and they must be exactly the same to be part of the same pool. You asked "Does ADO.NET exclude connection pool size and application name while identifying a unique connection?" and I answered it correctly. My answer still stands. I hope you figure out whatever issue you are experiencing. And perhaps post a different question as it relates to SQL Profiler.

Comment: Thank you William for your help. The issue is not with profiler but with ADO.Net. I get the same application name whether I capture via profiler or ssms. I have upvoted your response but I am still not sure if ADO.net considers application name to identify unique connections while creating connection pools.

Comment: Thanks for the upvote. ADO.NET looks at the entire connection string, not just the application name. I updated my answer with more from the official Docs. If you are still questioning how connection pools are created, you should post a question on the official Microsoft Git Hub repository for .NET.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer Williams. I was planning to dig through the source code to check if I can get a better insight.

Comment: you were right about how ado.net identifies unique connection string. It was an issue with the code. Thank you for your help